# Changing Values according to the row below

Tags: r

I have this data set that looks some thing like this:

```
id  chan. conv.
1    5     0
1    8     0
2    3     0
2    5     0
2    4     0
2    7     1
3    6     0
3    3     0
3    7     1
4    3     0
4    8     0
```

Basically whenever 7 occurs in the `chan.` column it means the product has been sold and when an 8 occurs it means it hasn't be sold. The `id` length can be very different and I want to know how I could remove the row with 7 or 8 but change the above row, so that it shows if the item has been converted or not. So the dataset will look something like this:

```
id  chan. conv.
1    5     0
2    3     0
2    5     0
2    4     1
3    6     0
3    3     1
4    3     0
```

Comment: So you want to remove rows where `chan.` == 7 or 8 and you want the number 1 to be placed one row up in `conv.` every time this occurs?

Comment: Yes, I know a for loop could do this but Im not sure how. I am quite new to R

Comment: So then shouldn't the first and last row (of your desired output) in `conv.` have a 1 because of the 8's in the second and last row?

Comment: Sorry when 8 occurs it means the product did not convert and then the data set moves onto another customer. So essentially I can remove the rows with 8 without changing anything. It is just the rows with 7 that means the product has converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(conv. = lead(case_when(chan. == 7 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))) %>% 
  filter(chan. != 7 & chan. != 8)
```

If you're certain that every time `conv. == 7` the respective row in `chan.` equals 1, you can skip the `case_when` step and try the following:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(conv. = lead(conv.)) %>% 
  filter(chan. != 7 & chan. != 8)
```

Which returns:

```
  id chan. conv.
1  1     5     0
2  2     3     0
3  2     5     0
4  2     4     1
5  3     6     0
6  3     3     1
7  4     3     0
```